# Careers 2.0 RSS feed always showing me duplicates in FeedDemon Pro

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, feed

I'm using the following feed to the careers stack exchange:

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed?searchTerm=c%2b%2b%2c+php%2c+web%2c+jquery&location=06443&range=40

I'm getting duplicates of the jobs that match, all of the time. Is their a problem in that a guid is missing in the RSS so that FeedDemon can't realize that it's already seen those jobs? When I check again, later, I get another set of the dups.

See the screenshot at

http://jacketboy.s3.amazonaws.com/stack/ScreenClip96341.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've added the  element to the feed. Has it improved?

Comment: Ya... I think it is fixed. Will let you know if I see it again.