# Add a link to RSS feeds on Careers

Tags: support, jobs

So I guess careers.stackoverflow.com [has an RSS feed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96341/careers-2-0-rss-feed-always-showing-me-duplicates-in-feeddemon-pro) but there's no link to it [on the search page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=php&location=&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles&offersrelocation=true). Maybe such a link could be added?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RSS feeds are in the search jobs sidebar box. They reflect the current search parameters. They are tiny.

[image: rss on search jobs]